# How to remove evolution from debian but keep gnome

Tags: debian, gnome, debian-based

Well it's in the title

I did try this:

aptitude unmarkauto gnome-desktop-environment gdm-themes gnome-themes-extras gnome-games libpam-gnome-keyring gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg rhythmbox synaptic system-config-printer totem-mozilla epiphany-extensions serpentine gnome-app-install arj avahi-daemon deluge+ gnome_

Comment: Wrong website: try [Super User](http://superuser.com/).